# Why git describe does not give me dirty suffix when untracked file existed?

Tags: git

`git status` show me some untracked files. But `git describe` did not give me dirty flag. Why?

```sh
user@host:~$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 16 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
user@host:~$ git describe --dirty --tags
v0.3-4-3-geadf778
```

Answer (score 0):

`--dirty` looks for uncommitted modifications on tracked files ; untracked files are completely ignored.

If you want to make git "aware" of extra files, you can use `git add file1 file2 ...` or `git add --intent-to-add file1 file2 ...`

Comment: thank you very much. The command `git describe` is executed in automatical build script. If some one forgets to run `git add` manually, the version name will be a wrong one. Is there a  better solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Git behavior has changed over time. Older versions indeed treat untracked files as dirty state. Here is a comparison of Ubuntu 20.04's packaged git against the version of git manually compiled from source:

```
root@a8f03338d558:~# git --version
git version 2.25.1
root@a8f03338d558:~# git describe --match=NeVeRmAtCh --always --dirty
4f087b8-dirty
root@a8f03338d558:~# git/git --version
git version 2.39.0.rc2.23.g694cb1b2ab
root@a8f03338d558:~# git/git describe --match=NeVeRmAtCh --always --dirty
4f087b8
```

I wonder whether there exists an option, which aligns the behavior of older and newer versions of Git.

Comment: But my git with version 2.25.1 does not give dirty flag: `$ git --version
git version 2.25.1
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        b.c

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$ git describe --match=NeVeRmAtCh --always --dirty
3a77f28`

Comment: @progquester thanks for this info. It could be, that's why I think there should be a git config setting which controls this.